# error This is probably not a problem with npm

Tags: reactjs

This is what I have in my package.json

"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start

When I use the command: npm start, I get the error:

````
C:\xampp\htdocs\physicssimulation\node_modules\.bin\react-scripts:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo '$0' | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
    ```
````

Comment: You're on a windows machine, but it's trying to execute Unix commands, so that seems like an issue...

Comment: Thanks, OneCricketeer. I'm actually trying to create apps with React-Spring not just React but the start command in my package.json uses react-scripts. The package.json was created when I ran npm install and then I changed it to use the full directory after reading a post about it. I'm not sure that I'm doing this the right way to use React-Spring.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with React (or Spring's integration with it), but you should try running your commands from WSL2, Git bash, etc rather than CMD/powershell

Comment: Thanks, OneCricketeer. I executed npm start in git bash and got the exact same error.

Comment: Can you show the package json? I assume your app was created with `create-react-app`?

Comment: I used the commands from this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-spring-introduction-and-installation/ and created a new application before installing react-spring and now React is working but I still don't see how to create a react-spring app.

Answer (score 0):

try these :

```json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

if again! show this error then put these commands in a command line:

```sh
npm init -y
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks, Aran. The react part is working now. I'm just going to follow the rest of the commands at the web site I linked to and I think I'll be able to do it in a while from now.

Comment: I got the simple example from the web site up and running now.